# Функция без использования return: как выполнить?

Tags: php

```
    <?php
    function my_func($my_var){
    ...
}
    $a = 20;
    my_func($a);
    echo $a; //здесь должно быть выведено 30
```

Согласно данной части кода нужно доделать так, чтобы функция увеличивала значение $my_var на 10. Использовать **return** в функции запрещено.

Comment: Передавать по ссылке?

Comment: а как избежать отсутствие return? Вы знаете? напишите плиз тогда

Comment: А вы пробовали сделать это с использованием ссылок? Покажите что у вас получилось и не получилось, ответ будет выглядеть как издевательство. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Pavel, я понял, спасибо. Не знаk что это будет работать без return

Comment: function my_func(&$my_var){
    $my_var += 10;
}

Comment: ответ помог????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем референс:

```
function my_func(&$my_var){
    $my_var += 10;
}

$a = 20;
my_func($a);
echo $a;
```